# error while naming a text file with a large name

Tags: python-3.x, string, file, text

I am trying to rename a text file with following name:

```
MLPClassifier(activation='relu', alpha=0.0001, batch_size='auto', beta_1=0.9,
       beta_2=0.999, early_stopping=True, epsilon=1e-08,
       hidden_layer_sizes=(181, 181, 181), learning_rate='constant',
       learning_rate_init=0.05, max_iter=100, momentum=0.9,
       nesterovs_momentum=True, power_t=0.5, random_state=None,
       shuffle=True, solver='adam', tol=0.0001, validation_fraction=0.1,
       verbose=False, warm_start=False)
```

when I copy paste the above name and try to rename the file, I am able to rename it but trying the same thing using a Python program gives the error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "MLPClassifier(activation='relu', alpha=0.0001, batch_size='auto', beta_1=0.9,\n       beta_2=0.999, early_stopping=True, epsilon=1e-08,\n       hidden_layer_sizes=(181, 181, 181), learning_rate='constant',\n       learning_rate_init=0.05, max_iter=100, momentum=0.9,\n       nesterovs_momentum=True, power_t=0.5, random_state=None,\n       shuffle=True, solver='adam', tol=0.0001, validation_fraction=0.1,\n       verbose=False, warm_start=False).txt"
```

Here is my code:

```
modelDetailsAndResults = modelName+'.txt'
output_file = open(modelDetailsAndResults,"w", encoding="utf8")
output_file.write("model details:")
output_file.write(modelName)
output_file.close()
```

Comment: are you sure you want to name your file with newlines and a bunch of special characters?

Comment: it will be fine if there will be no special characters or new lines

Comment: @AnthonySottile May I know how can I do that if I eliminate special characters and new lines?

Comment: Probably can do something like `re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9_.,=]', '', filename) ` to eliminate any characters not in that character class

Comment: @AnthonySottile Actually it is not because of special characters but it is because of the length. I have put a randon string below. If you try to put few more characters in it, it will give error in remaning

Comment: As you might have As you might have  expected from reading the previous previos section text filesexp As you might might have As you might As you As you might As you might have As you might As you might As you might have As you might have As you might

Comment: @AnthonySottile thank you it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you cannot rename a file above of certain characters. It is somewhat I guess around 251, not sure though. The number of characters you are using is way much